# Check byte size for Javascript string

Tags: javascript, oracle, byte

I want to do some byte checking for string using Javascript and for that I've the following code:

```
const byteSize = str => new Blob([str]).size;
```

This thing work for me.
For example

```
 byteSize("Susan 002 UK ACM Testing ")
```

This one returns 29bytes to me.

Now in the server side I user the `lengthB` function of Oracle which returns 31bytes for the same string.

Not sure how Oracle calculates it internally but I need some modification in the Javascript code so that it always returns same value like Oracle.

Comment: What is the issue now?

Comment: @SelakaNanayakkara Javascript size byte value with this function and Oracle lengthb function response is not always same. I want to modify the Javascript function so that it always returns same value like Oracle.

Comment: Are you sure that both systems use the same charset? JavaScript's Blob encodes strings in utf-8. Maybe your server side is using a different charset?

Comment: @Marble Not sure what format oracle uses. But in javascript side do we have option to modify the encode format while checking? Is it configurable?

Comment: @IndranilMondal from what I read, the charset in Oracle should be able to be set by the developer. I don't know what the default charset is. You should find out which charset Oracle uses. You could try this: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/determining-character-set-oracle-database

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can use:

```sql
SELECT DUMP(column_name, 1010)
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (column_name VARCHAR2(4000));
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES ('Susan 002 UK ACM Testing ');
```

Outputs:

| DUMP(COLUMN_NAME,1010) |
| --- |
| Typ=1 Len=29 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 83,117,115,97,110,32,48,48,50,32,85,75,32,65,67,77,32,84,101,115,116,105,110,103,32,240,159,152,138 |

Which tells you both the byte length, character set and the byte values.

Your Oracle data has 31 bytes so you need to compare the bytes from the two strings and work out what the difference is and where the invisible characters are.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eJTcOpxj)

---

In JavaScript, you can create an equivalent byte array and convert it to a string using:

```js
let bytes = new Uint8Array([83,117,115,97,110,32,48,48,50,32,85,75,32,65,67,77,32,84,101,115,116,105,110,103,32,240,159,152,138]);
let str = new TextDecoder("UTF-8").decode(bytes);
console.log(str);
```

Which should output the same value as Oracle.